# Max concurrent connections for Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, connection, tomcat8

I have 2 server AWS EC2 with each server is: CPU=2 RAM=15GB.

I using domain http

I using AWS ELB for 2 serser.

I using tomcat 8 for 2 server.

I using AB for test connect but have failed requests.

```
ab -n 4000 -c 4000 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://mywebsite.com
```

I want ask how many concurrent connections request to my server?

Answer (score 1):

default is 10000

Here is from tomcat 8 source code, you can set it by yourself.

```
    private int maxConnections = 10000;
public void setMaxConnections(int maxCon) {
    this.maxConnections = maxCon;
    LimitLatch latch = this.connectionLimitLatch;
    if (latch != null) {
        // Update the latch that enforces this
        if (maxCon == -1) {
            releaseConnectionLatch();
        } else {
            latch.setLimit(maxCon);
        }
    } else if (maxCon > 0) {
        initializeConnectionLatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: If default is 10,000 then why when I test with AB 4000 have failed request?

Comment: Tomcat 8 default has 200 threads to handle the requests, others will pending on the queue, how  does AB define the failed request(time out time?)

Comment: I set maxThreads="2000" in server.xml. AB result:

`Complete requests:      4000
Failed requests:        2568
Keep-Alive requests:    2918
Requests per second:    1256.10 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3184.460 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.796 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          281.56 [Kbytes/sec] received
Total:         33 1062 790.4    891    3169`

Comment: My tomcat setting:  `<Connector  port="8080" 
                maxThreads="2000"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                socket.appReadBufSize="1024"   
                socket.appWriteBufSize="1024"
                bufferSize="1024"
                connectionTimeout="200000"
                redirectPort="8443" />`

Comment: You cannot set so much threads, threads switch will take much time, so it will slow the whole service

Comment: My server is very strong. I want concurrent connections to my tomcat ~ 5000 - 6000. Can I do it?

Comment: No, don't set too many execute threads, by the way, concurrent connections is not concurrent execute threads. I don't know about the AB, i want to know how does AB judge the request failed?

Comment: <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
   connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" /><Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="30" 
   minSpareThreads="4"/>

Comment: I just try and request failed increase

Comment: Can you use this? ab -n 4000 -c 10 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://mywebsite.com

Comment: Did you configured the AWS ELB time out or max connections?

Comment: I want using -c 4000 because my system have many request per second. AWS ELB timeout = 600 minutes

Comment: For NIO and NIO2 the default is 10000. For APR/native, the default is 8192.

Note that for APR/native on Windows, the configured value will be reduced to the highest multiple of 1024 that is less than or equal to maxConnections. This is done for performance reasons.
If set to a value of -1, the maxConnections feature is disabled and connections are not counted. Which server tomcat deployed on? or you can try to set maxConnections to -1

Comment: Sorry, i didn't meet this scenario before, I guess it is due to the http network issue for a great mount to requests. you can add some log in tomcat source code to identifier whether it is this issue. Below is the tomcat default accept request code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tomcat source code`SocketChannel socket = null;
                    try {
                        // Accept the next incoming connection from the server
                        // socket
                        socket = serverSock.accept();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        //we didn't get a socket
                        countDownConnection();
                        // Introduce delay if necessary
                        errorDelay = handleExceptionWithDelay(errorDelay);
                        // re-throw
                        throw ioe;
                    }`

Comment: Tomcat accepts the request one by one, so i guess some request would be missed, you can add log to count the request that identify this issue, good luck